# The problem of the joint arrangement of two TextViews with a large volume of text

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview, android-linearlayout

There is a horizontal LinearLayout in which 2 TextViews are located. The problem is as follows: if there is a large amount of text in the first TextView, then it completely overlaps the second TextView, as if pushing it into an invisible area, despite the fact that the latter also has text. I need part of the text in the first TextView to be hidden (I used the maxLines and ellipsize attributes) when the text is too large, but at the same time I need the text of the second TextView to be visible too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="random text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried the android:maxWidth attribute. But it seems to me that this is not quite right.

Comment: Give both TextViews `layout_weight=1` and `layout_width=0`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Tenfour04's comment.

> Give both TextViews layout_weight=1 and layout_width=0. –

Solution is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="random text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The solution looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        tools:text="random text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```